# How to get top committers who make certain percentage of the commits?

Tags: git, version-control, commit

I want to show top committers who have commits above the 20% of the all commits in the repository.

Example:

```
Total commits: 100
user1: 35
user2: 30
user3: 25
user4: 10
```

Expected Output:

```
35 user1
30 user2
25 user3
```

Answer (score 0):

`git shortlog -ns` is OK on my environment.

git version 1.7.9.5

Comment: git shortlog -ns is OK with sorting All user but I want to add some filter like display commiters that have above 20% percentage commits

Comment: @notch then，you need parse the output.

Comment: hmm, so I can not this filter by sending any argument as a parameter, right?

Comment: @notch yeah，you need resort  to other tools, I think.

Answer (score 0):

`git shortlog -sne` will give you an output like this:

```
297  John White <john.white@ic...>
 93  Alex Peroni <alex.peroni@gm...>
 56  Paul Harrington <paul.hton@pa...>
```

Which you can easily copy to Excel and sum, and then get your 20% committers.

---

Just my two cents: Number of commits is not a great metric to take any good conclusions. Some people create tiny commits for everything (for no reason), others create massive commits that should actually be lots of smaller ones...

Your top 20% will likely be people who do not care about keeping a clean history (and squashing commits, etc.), and are always all over the place, rather than focusing on a specific feature. Your good devs, will be somewhere in the middle.

This reminds me of this post by Scott Hanselman: [GitHub Activity Guilt and the Coder's FitBit](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GitHubActivityGuiltAndTheCodersFitBit.aspx)

Comment: My aim is not to evaluate the results, but thanks for additional info

Comment: @notch: So out of curiosity, why do you want this info?

Comment: is a question in a project scope about mining version control system. I guess, different tools and scripts can analyze the wide statistics about version control like 'gitstats'

Comment: gitstats almost meets all I need. Just I can not give a specific time frame, --after or --before flags for filtering commits by date, and repository has too much size, so i need filter by date.

Answer (score 0):

`git shortlog` combined with `awk` can give you the solution:

First, run `git shortlog -sn` (plus any other option you require, such as `--before`, `--after`, `--no-merges` or specifying a commit range, e.g. `v1..v5`) and store the output in a file:

```
git shortlog -sn > shortlog
```

Next, get the total with `awk`:

```
total=$(awk '{s+=$1}END{print s}' shortlog)
```

Finally, calculate the percentage for each author and skip those which do not meet your threshold (e.g. 10%):

```
awk -v total=$total '{pct=$1/total}pct>0.1{print pct,$0}' shortlog
```

Example output:

```
0.147815   7509 Junio C Hamano
```

Of course, outputting only the name or email is also possible. To print the email, specify `-e` for shortlog. To print only the name/email without count, use `{print $2}` with tab as delimiter:

```
awk -F'\t' -v total=$total '{pct=$1/total}pct>0.1{print $2}' shortlog
```